# Log2Hs duplicates all symbols in the console logger handler, how to fix it?

Tags: haskell, logging, console

I started to use [Log4Hs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/log4hs) library. My configuration for `app` logger is:

```yaml
  sinks:
      app:
        handlers:
        - console
        - rotate
        propagate: false
  handlers:
    console:
      type: StreamHandler
      level: DEBUG
      formatter: message
      stream: stdout
    rotate:
      type: RotatingFileHandler
      level: DEBUG
      formatter: long
      file: /.tmp/myapp.log
      encoding: utf8
      maxBytes: 1048576
      backupCount: 10
  formatters:
    message: "{message}"
    long: "{asctime:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%6Q%z} - {level} - {logger}] {message}"
  disabled: false
```

And I use `$(debug) ...` in main thread and in **forked threads**, I initialize it once in the main thread as the documentation says it.

The problem is that the output from forked threads looks like:

```
ffrroommLLiisstt  [[]];;  nneewwIIppss::
```

for both cases - "stderr" and "stdout". This example is from one forked thread, not from two, so duplication of every symbol happens due to one (forked) thread, not two (no races and similar). I tried "propagate: true/false" - it does not help. The problem is relevant for forked threads trying to log, not for the main thread!

**Important nuance: duplication happens only on console, not in the file "myapp.log".**

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

just found the problem, I had

```hs
hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
```

in the main func. Without it (or with `LineBuffering`) is seems to work fine.

-detouk